# Creating interceptors with Autofac and MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy, method-interception

I need to create a performance monitoring interceptor that will be hooked up via Autofac. Unfortunately, it's for an MVC3 project, meaning that I'm using Autofac 2.6.3, because Autofac 3 is only compatible with MVC4. As such, I cannot use the `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2` Nuget package, because it isn't compatible with MVC3.

I've found `AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2`, which is compatible with `Autofac 2.6.3`. The problem is, the Nuget package doesn't install due to a version mismatch between the dependencies. The problem is highlighted below:

- AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2

  - Depends on 'Autofac (>= 2.4.5.724)'
  - Depends on 'Castle.Core (>= 2.5.2)'.
  - Depends on 'Castle.DynamicProxy (>= 2.2.0)'.

    - Depends on 'Castle.Core (= 1.2.0)'.

I get the following Nuget package install error:

> Updating 'Castle.Core 2.5.2' to 'Castle.Core 1.2.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2' that is compatible with 'Castle.Core 1.2.0'

**How can I perform method interception with MVC3 and Autofac?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I can install 'DynamicProxy2', thanks to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2011/08/18/using-autofac-dynamicproxy2-interceptors-with-mvc3-part-1.aspx)

Basically, after installing `AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2` and getting the error, I need to install it again with the `-ignoredependencies` flag and it installs OK.

Run this command:

> install-package autofaccontrib.dynamicproxy2

Followed by this command:

> install-package autofaccontrib.dynamicproxy2 -ignoredependencies